# How to copy records from parent to child in same table using MS SQL CTE

Tags: sql-server, recursion, cursor, common-table-expression

I have requirement like copy same parent records to N child with same table. **The only difference in the data is Parent Id and Client Id**, I have to copy Parent records as it is to child with only ParentId and ClientId value change.
- Parent records may be 1 to 2000 which need to be moved for each client.
- Child records (repeat 1 to 1000) different child.

I have implemented the requirement using SQL Server Cursor but this is extensively very slow if we have parent records more than 1000 and Child (repeat entries) more than 1500. So i would like to know whether it is possible to use CTE instead cursor to gain performance for the bulk insertion.

I am using following code to copy parent records to each client:

```
DECLARE @id bigint;
--Get list of client which will repeat the rows from Master entries
--This will return three rows Id:1,5,7
DECLARE client_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Id FROM Client WHERE ClientName like 'info%' 
OPEN client_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM client_cursor INTO @id;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        /*....*/
        /* Other business logic performed here */
        /*....*/
        INSERT INTO Resources (ParentId,ClientId,Location,Title,[Status],Alert)
        --This will return two rows Id:1,2
        SELECT Id,@id,Location,Title,[Status],Alert FROM Resources WHERE ParentId IS NULL AND ClientId IS NULL  

        FETCH NEXT FROM client_cursor INTO @id
    END 
CLOSE client_cursor;
DEALLOCATE client_cursor;
```

Following are the screen shot before and after adding bulk Parent records to Child using above code snippet.
[image: Result of the Query]

```
-- Table Creation
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Client](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientName] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Client] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Resources](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [bigint] NULL,
    [ClientId] [bigint] NULL,
    [Location] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Alert] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Resources] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- Default Data Insertion
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Client] ON 
INSERT [dbo].[Client] ([Id], [ClientName]) VALUES (1, N'Infosstretch')
INSERT [dbo].[Client] ([Id], [ClientName]) VALUES (2, N'Microsoft')
INSERT [dbo].[Client] ([Id], [ClientName]) VALUES (3, N'Sun System')
INSERT [dbo].[Client] ([Id], [ClientName]) VALUES (4, N'IBM')
INSERT [dbo].[Client] ([Id], [ClientName]) VALUES (5, N'Infosys')
INSERT [dbo].[Client] ([Id], [ClientName]) VALUES (6, N'TCS')
INSERT [dbo].[Client] ([Id], [ClientName]) VALUES (7, N'Infomatica')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Client] OFF

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Resources] ON 
INSERT [dbo].[Resources] ([Id], [ParentId], [ClientId], [Location], [Title], [Status], [Alert]) VALUES (1, NULL, NULL, N'India', N'Master A', N'New', N'Issue with location')
INSERT [dbo].[Resources] ([Id], [ParentId], [ClientId], [Location], [Title], [Status], [Alert]) VALUES (2, NULL, NULL, N'Australia', N'Master B', N'Updated', N'No major issue')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Resources] OFF
```

Comment: why don't you try with while loop

Comment: This is a complicated enough post. If you want to enhance the possibility that somebody will help you then consider adding a sql script for creating the schema and the sample data of your post.

Comment: I have also tried with while loop to get one by one Client to process but again this will create number of read operation in database for each individual Client. i Have also attached the DB Script if to help community to avoid write from beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably some reasons from your business rules that are removed for brevity here, but why not something like this?

```
INSERT #Resources
SELECT
    R.Id AS ParentId,
    C.Id AS ClientId,
    R.Location,
    R.Title,
    R.Status,
    R.Alert
FROM #Resources R
    CROSS JOIN #Client C
WHERE R.ParentId IS NULL AND R.ClientId IS NULL -- Root level
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #Resources WHERE ParentId = R.Id) -- Not already populated
    -- AND /* Other business logic performed here */
```

Comment: Perfect answer! exactly i am looking for this solution. Can you please explain why you have added following statement `NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #Resources WHERE ParentId = R.Id)`

Comment: I added the `NOT EXISTS` clause so that in case this runs more than once, it ensures to only push records to clients for resources that have not already been pushed out (avoiding dupes). Glad it works for you!

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification!